# Java - Cannot Use Class From Same Directory

Tags: java, class, compiler-errors

I'm trying to call the Game class (that resides in src/main/java/Game.java)  from within the Main class (that resides in src/main/java/Main.java), but I'm getting this error:

> Main.java:3: error: cannot find symbol Game hangman = new Game(); symbol:   class Game; location: class Main::: Main.java:3: error: cannot find symbol Game hangman = new Game(); symbol: class Game; location: class Main::: 2 errors; error: compilation failed

Here is the code that is in the Main.java file:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Game hangman = new Game();
    hangman.initialize();
  }
}
```

Here is the code that is in the Game.java file:

```
public class Game {
  private String randomWord;
  private int maxGuesses;
  private int guessCount;

  public Game () {
    this.maxGuesses = 8;
    this.guessCount = 0;
  }

  public void incrementGuessCount () {
    this.guessCount++;
  }

  public String generateRandomWord () {
    String[] words = {"puppy", "pool", "avalanche"};
    String result = words[(int) Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
    this.randomWord = result;
    return result;
  }

  public void initialize () {
    String word = this.generateRandomWord();
    System.out.println(word);
  }
}
```

I'm using WSL, and this is my current Java version.

> openjdk 11.0.13 2021-10-19
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+8-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.13+8-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: How are you compiling your code?

Comment: Are you using packages?

Comment: The "classic" answer (prior to Java 9 [modules](https://learnjava.co.in/what-is-the-difference-between-a-module-and-a-package/)) is to organize your Java classes in packages, which are in turn organized by subdirectory.  That's probably a good solution here: just use packages.

Comment: @tgdavies thanks for asking. I simply ran the Main.java file using "java Main.java" command from terminal. I'm new to Java, so bear with me- hehe.

Comment: You need to compile the code first using javac

Comment: @ScaryWombat I'm not using packages, but can learn to make one for these classes so that they're compatible. I just figured I shouldn't have to since they're in the same directory.

Comment: Running a `.java` file directly with `java` only works for single source file programs. You need to compile first with `javac Main.java Game.java`. Then you can run with `java Main`.

Comment: @paulsm4 I'll get accustomed to packages! I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: @tgdavies Nice! This is getting me a new error- which is always good. I'll get back to this asap once I work through this new error.

Comment: @tgdavies I'm not sure how to make your comment the answer, but it is the answer. First, I had to update my "javac" so that it's the same version as my "java". Second, I had to compile my java files using "javac Main.java Game.java". Third, I had to run the code using "java Main" (NOT "java Main.java").

Here are some links that helped me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57359396/how-to-fix-error-class-found-on-application-class-path-main-in-java-for-visu
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609083/update-alternatives-warning-etc-alternatives-java-is-dangling

Comment: Here are some other links that would have helped you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216